# SOAP call PHP not sending all parameters

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I am trying to make a SOAP call in PHP while I am trying to pass some parameters some of them are never sent. I do not really know if it is a problem about building the **LoginYInsertarEvento2Params** object or it is more related about the soap call.

This is the object that I build for making the call

```
 $LoginYInsertarEvento2Params = array(
         "SystemUser" => "XXXXX",
         "Password" => "XXXXXX",
         "Dominio" => $registration,
         "NroSerie" => $terminal_serial,
         "Codigo" => "",
         "Latitud" => $latitude,
         "Longitud" => $longitude,
         "Altitud" => "0",
         "Velocidad" => $speed,
         "FechaHoraEvento" => date('c', strtotime($fecha_evento)),
         "FechaHoraRecepcion" => date('c', strtotime($fecha_registro)),
         "Valido" => true,
         "Sensores" =>array ( ["Temperatura" => $temp], ["Luminosidad" => $lum] )
       );
```

This the request:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:ns1="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:LoginYInsertarEvento2>
                <ns1:SystemUser>XXXXX</ns1:SystemUser>
                <ns1:Password>XXXXX</ns1:Password>
                <ns1:Dominio>XXXXXX</ns1:Dominio>
                <ns1:NroSerie>-1</ns1:NroSerie>
                <ns1:Codigo></ns1:Codigo>
                <ns1:Latitud>40.348054</ns1:Latitud>
                <ns1:Longitud>-3.681576</ns1:Longitud>
                <ns1:Altitud>0</ns1:Altitud>
                <ns1:Velocidad>0</ns1:Velocidad>
                <ns1:FechaHoraEvento>2020-10-09T12:50:40+02:00</ns1:FechaHoraEvento>
                <ns1:FechaHoraRecepcion>2020-10-09T12:50:56+02:00</ns1:FechaHoraRecepcion>
                <ns1:Valido>true</ns1:Valido>
                <ns1:Sensores>
                    <ns1:pSensor/>
                    <ns1:pSensor/>
                </ns1:Sensores>
            </ns1:LoginYInsertarEvento2>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And it should be like this one...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <LoginYInsertarEvento2 xmlns="http://unisolutions.com.ar/">
                <SystemUser>XXXXXX</SystemUser>
                <Password>xxxxxxxx</Password>
                <Dominio>XXXXXXX</Dominio>
                <NroSerie>-1</NroSerie>
                <Codigo />
                <Latitud>41.748311</Latitud>
                <Longitud>-0.848768</Longitud>
                <Altitud>274</Altitud>
                <Velocidad>0</Velocidad>
                <FechaHoraEvento>2020-10-06T09:36:56</FechaHoraEvento>
                <FechaHoraRecepcion>2020-10-06T09:36:56</FechaHoraRecepcion>
                <Valido>true</Valido>
                <Sensores>
                    <pSensor>
                        <Clave>Temperatura</Clave>
                        <Valor>11.6</Valor>
                    </pSensor>
                    <pSensor>
                        <Clave>Luminosidad</Clave>
                        <Valor>0</Valor>
                    </pSensor>
                </Sensores>
            </LoginYInsertarEvento2>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by what you expect your output to be. Try changing the structure to look like this:

```
$LoginYInsertarEvento2Params = array(
    "SystemUser" => "XXXXX",
    "Password" => "XXXXXX",
    "Dominio" => $registration,
    "NroSerie" => $terminal_serial,
    "Codigo" => "",
    "Latitud" => $latitude,
    "Longitud" => $longitude,
    "Altitud" => "0",
    "Velocidad" => $speed,
    "FechaHoraEvento" => date('c', strtotime($fecha_evento)),
    "FechaHoraRecepcion" => date('c', strtotime($fecha_registro)),
    "Valido" => true,
    "Sensores" =>array (
        ["Clave" => "Temperatura", "Valor" => $temp],
        ["Clave" => "Luminosidad", "Valor" => $lum]
    )
);
```

I may be wrong, but it just looks like the Sensores structure is incorrect.

Comment: It is possible, I am pretty new to PHP always worked in Java... I will try it, thanks!